Adjust magnitude of vectors so sum equals certain vector
I'm trying to figure out how to get a target vector in 3D from the sum of other vectors.
The direction of the vector components are fixed, but I can adjust their magnitudes, up to a certain value. They are essentially the bases of the Vector space, but with a maximum magnitude value. I want to get the values of these magnitudes so that the sum of the vector components is the closest to the target vector.
How do I figure out these magnitudes if I have 2, 3, and 4 vector components?

Its not real clear what you ask ,so please give an example of your vectors you want to adjust.

There are multiple ways in which you could interpret "as close as possible" but one way is to use constrained least squares, which minimizes the quadratic distance.
If you have a target vector $\mathbf{d}$ and a set of usable vectors $\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2,...,\mathbf{v}_k$ then put them as columns into a matrix $R=[\mathbf{v}_1 |\mathbf{v}_2 | ... | \mathbf{v}_k]$ and let $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,...,x_k)$ denote the the magnitudes of each vector i.e. $x_1$ is the magnitude of $\mathbf{v}_1$ and $x_k$ is the magnitude of $\mathbf{v}_k$. You want to minimize
$$\textstyle||R \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{d} ||^2 = ||\sum_{\ell=1}^k (x_\ell \mathbf{v}_\ell) - \mathbf{d} ||^2$$
with the constraint that for a given maximum magnitude $L$ that they are multiplied with we have $\mathbf{x}<L\mathbf{1}$, where $\mathbf{1}$ is a vector of ones.
There are various solvers available online. As an example, in Julia you can use the JuMP package and a solver from here that has "QP" next to it. Ipopt works very well in my experience.
